Como puedo ignorar un archivo en tiempo de compilacion en flutter web
Tengo un problema con una libreria en flutter al mometo de ejecutar flutter web uno de los archivos que me genera la libreria me da error estoy tratando de ignorarlo con el archivo build.yaml pero noi me funciona,
 targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      exclude:
        - lib/data/services/isar/**.dart
        -lib/data/services/isar/model_isar/orden_document_isar.g.dart
        - lib/data/services/isar/model_isar/orden_document_isar.dart
        - lib/data/services/isar/isar_db.dart
       
      

